# What happens to subscribers if they join a Journey in Marketing Cloud after an email action send date has passed?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am looking for the best practice scenario to set up a "course-based" email Journey in Journey Builder.

Subscribers sign up to the course which sends *x* number of emails over the same number of days. These emails are tied to a date e.g. the course begins on the 1st so the first email is sent on the 1st, the second email is sent on the 2nd, the third email on the 3rd etc.

If I set each email to send against a specific date and time, would a subscriber who joins partway through effectively skip the already-passed dates and just start receiving the emails from the date they joined e.g. if they joined on the 2nd (after the second email had been sent) the first email they would receive is the third email on the 3rd?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: all subscribers start at the beginning of the journey if you have a wait until step and its in the past they subscriber will simply move through to the next activity immediately

Comment: That's really helpful and very clear. Thanks so much @EazyE.